# phpcurl cannot put to Amazon s3

Tags: php, curl, amazon-s3, php-curl

If I  PUT to Amazon S3 using curl the request and response work.  Using phpcurl I get a SignatureDoesNotMatch error.  But the signature is the same in  either case I think.  Below I have the curl request and the php request.

curl request

```
PUT long_amazon_url_here
Host: s3.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/pdf
x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256
Content-Length: 655786
Expect: 100-continue
```

php curl request

```
PUT long_amazon_url_here
Accept: */*
x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256
Content-Length: 656028
Content-Type: application/pdf; boundary=------------------------53e1e1c959bffe27
Expect: 100-continue
```

The curl code is:

```
curl --verbose -X PUT -T file.pdf -H "Content-Type: application/pdf" -H "x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256" "long_amazon_url_here"
```

The php code is as follows:

```
$header = array(
"x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256",
"Content-Type: application/pdf");

$url = long_amazon_url_here 
$cFile = curl_file_create($fullPath_to_file);
$post = array('file_contents'=> $cFile);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Anyone know what I can change to make the phpcurl version work?

Comment: I strongly recommend using the AWS SDK for PHP to do this. There's no reason to try and do it yourself manually.

Comment: I am using pre-signed urls so I do not have any credentials - I looked at AWS SDK and I think it would  require I have them to be of use.

Comment: Where did you come up with `file_contents`? And why is `CURLOPT_POST` set to true? `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is not used for file uploads.

Comment: file_contents was in the post I was following to upload a file with php.  Maybe I am way off.  In phpcurl docs I see an option of specifying a file size but I thought the file had to be a postfield and thought  "file_contents" must be the convention to identify it.